# How to prevent mutation

Tags: javascript, immutability

I have been trying to write a function which calculates mixed bills, with NO MUTATION using ES6.
I have a code below, what it does is, it takes group of people's given money, adds all of them in order to get the total amount and then loops and then divides to length of the users in order to get how much it comes to per person. And then I'm subtracting per-person share from users amount, so list contains either negative/positive or 0, depending how much they have contributed into total bill. Then goes filters of users for people who have greater than 0 and less than 0 in order to extract negative and positive amounts.

So far the code works fine and the output as I expected, however I'm using let variable which is constantly changing, which leads to mutation from my understanding, is there any other way of preventing mutation in this code,

You can view the code on snippet

```js
const users = [
  { id: 1, username: "John One", amount: 50 },
  { id: 2, username: "John Two", amount: 75 },
  { id: 3, username: "John Three", amount: 100 },
  { id: 4, username: "John Four", amount: 125 },
  { id: 5, username: "John five", amount: 150 },
  { id: 6, username: "John six", amount: 50 },
  { id: 7, username: "John seven", amount: 150 },
  { id: 8, username: "John eight", amount: 250 },
  { id: 9, username: "John nine", amount: 150 },
  { id: 10, username: "John Ten", amount: 100 },
]


const total = users.reduce((acc, user) => acc + user.amount, 0);
const perPersonShare = total / users.length;
const sortedUsers = users.map((user) => { return { ...user, amount: user.amount - perPersonShare, hasToPay: [] } });
const negativeAmount = sortedUsers.filter(user => user.amount < 0);
const positiveAmount = sortedUsers.filter(user => user.amount > 0);


const res = positiveAmount.reduce((acc, user) => {

  let balance = user.amount;

  return acc.map((ower) => {

    if (ower.amount === 0 || balance === 0) return ower;

    if (balance <= Math.abs(ower.amount)) {
      const updated = {
        ...ower,
        hasToPay: [...ower.hasToPay, { to: user.username, amount: balance }],
        amount: ower.amount + balance,
      };

      balance = 0;
      return updated;
    }

    if (balance >= Math.abs(ower.amount)) {
      const updated = {
        ...ower,
        hasToPay: [...ower.hasToPay, { to: user.username, amount: Math.abs(ower.amount) }],
        amount: 0,
      };

      balance = balance + ower.amount;
      return updated;
    }

    return ower;

  });


}, negativeAmount);

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, 0, 2))
console.log(perPersonShare);
console.log(total);
```

Comment: I am not sure what your question/problem is. What is mutating exactly? What variable/object?

Comment: What benefit do you think you'll gain by removing mutation of variables holding primitive values? Because it seems like the only thing mutating is `balance`...

Comment: Reassigning values to variables is not the same as mutating objects. I don't see any mutation happening in your snippet.

Comment: I was just curious to know wether i can prevent mutation primitive (balance)

Comment: If you want a variable to be `non-REassignable` then simply declare it as `const`. If you want an Object to be immutable - then simply use `Object.freeze()`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this so my answer may work or not, but You can use `Object.freeze()` to freeze the object but instead of using arrays to define users you can define them using objects. It is from my understanding

here is some links I found they might be useful to you

https://roclv.gitbooks.io/redux-getting-started/content/09.redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread.html

https://medium.com/@fknussel/arrays-objects-and-mutations-6b23348b54aahttps://medium.com/@fknussel/arrays-objects-and-mutations-6b23348b54aa